Rigid body not working properly with curve modifier collision
I was making a conveyor belt for a little explainer video and stuck with a problem. I made belt using simple mesh with array and curve modifier. So when I move mesh, belt moves along curve. Everything looks and works fine. But for some reason all rigid body object stops considering curve modifier on a passive object when it has any keyframes. Everything works fine in realtime when objects drops on belt and I can move mesh but as soon as there is keyframe on it all objects acts like there is no curve modifier and just falls onto source mesh with array on it (or even ignores it completely).
I`ve made new blender file at home to repeat this issue.
Here it is: 

